# Finding the distance between two points in 3D space, Python

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a problem with a task. According to the condition of the problem, two points p1, p2 with xyz coordinates are given, you need to find the distance between these points in 3D space using the class. It seems that the task is simple in itself, but the difficulty for me is that the calculation of the distance must be carried out using the method with only one distance(other) parameter, and I don’t understand how this can be done if two variables are required, which will be give the coordinates of two points, and in the method we can use only one.

I tried to do like this, but I get an error (unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'):

```
from math import sqrt


class Point3D:
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @staticmethod
    def distance(other):
        return sqrt((other[0][0] - other[1][0]) ** 2 + (other[0][1] - other[1][1]) ** 2 + (other[0][2] - other[1][2]) ** 2)

p1 = [1, 2, 3]
p2 = [3, 2, 1]
s1 = Point3D(*p1)
s2 = Point3D(*p2)
print(Point3D.distance((s1, s2)))

>>>unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Also I tried to do like this, but it gives an error ('str' object has no attribute 'x')

```
# The rest of the code is the same

@staticmethod
    def distance(other):
        return sqrt((other[0].x - other[1].x) ** 2 + (other[0].y - other[1].y) ** 2 + (other[0].z - other[1].z) ** 2)

p1 = [1, 2, 3]
p2 = [3, 2, 1]
s1 = Point3D(*p1)
s2 = Point3D(*p2)
print(Point3D.distance((s1, s2)))

>>>AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Also code that works correctly but is not accepted because distance takes 2 parameters, but 1 is needed (this is an example of what code they don’t accept from me):

```
# The rest of the code is the same

 def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt((other.x1 - self.x1) ** 2 + (other.y1 - self.y1) ** 2 + (other.z1 - self.z1) ** 2)
 
p1 = [1, 2, 3]
p2 = [3, 2, 1]
point1 = Point3D(*p1)
point2 = Point3D(*p2)
print(point1.distance(point2))

>>>2.8284271247461903
```

Please help me fix the code so that it works with the distance(other) method and does not throw an error. You can remove @staticmethod if needed. I honestly don't know what to do anymore. I will be glad for any help

Comment: Hello Daniil, and welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that the last bit of code is correct and will only accept one argument as you demonstrated. The `self` argument doesn't need to be passed in and refers to the "owner" of the method (`point1` in this case).

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ that in the first and second snippets the code is as you wrote? Because I don't see `str` or any string anywhere in the code. And when I run snippet 1, I get the error `TypeError: 'Point3D' object is not subscriptable` which would make more sense.

Comment: Hello and thanks! The fact is that in Python, yes, everything is fine, but I’m currently doing an internship where my code checks the Python built into the site (I don’t know how to call it differently). He then issues all variables with values, so he also issues all errors. At the same time, what he can introduce is unknown to us, the trainees :( So I guess I posted my problem in vain, I apologize for that. 
Anyway, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 5):

Your code and error do not match.

When I try you code, it results in the following exception:

```
TypeError: 'Point3D' object is not subscriptable
```

This is understandable, because `Point3D` is not a sequence type.

Additionally, you have extraneous parenthesis in the distance call, so you are essentially only giving it one paramater (a 2-tuple).

Try this:

```
from math import sqrt


class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)

    def distance(self, p2):
        return sqrt((self.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (self.y - p2.y) ** 2 + (self.z - p2.z) ** 2)


s1 = Point3D(1, 2, 3)
s2 = Point3D(3, 2, 1)
print(s1.distance(s2))
```

Comment: no, the fact of the matter is that I need not distance(self, p), but only distance(p), that is, only one parameter. This is the condition of the task(

Comment: Look at the call of `distance`. Only one parameter (s2) is used...

Comment: All of your calls to and definitions of the `distance` method have one explicit (given by the caller) parameter.  In the case of `def distance(self, other)`, you've removed the `@staticmethod` qualifier, so now it is an instance method and so Python will call it with an extra `self` parameter providing the object on which the method is being called.  This is the key to your dilemma. 
 I'm guessing that it is this latter form that you're being asked for.  `self` doesn't count as a parameter since the caller doesn't supply it, but it is needed to provide the second point to be operated on.

Comment: I understand you, thanks for your help, but in my case, "self" is also a parameter :( At least, according to the condition of the problem. Thank you all very much for your help, but I'll probably write to the organizer about my problem tomorrow. I hope that he I now understand that I should have done this right away, and not publish my problem of local origin on the site.Sorry for the inconvenience!